# Values of $n$ for which $\lfloor 2 x\rfloor +\lfloor 4 x\rfloor +\lfloor 8 x\rfloor +\lfloor 20 x\rfloor =n$ has a solution

Tags: algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics, ceiling-and-floor-functions

$$\lfloor 2 x\rfloor +\lfloor 4 x\rfloor +\lfloor 8 x\rfloor +\lfloor 20 x\rfloor =n$$

How would you find the values of $n$ for which the equation has a solution under the condition that $n \leq 500$? I haven't really worked with equations involving floors before.

Comment: As a function of $x$, $f(x) = \lfloor 2 x\rfloor +\lfloor 4 x\rfloor +\lfloor 8 x\rfloor +\lfloor 20 x\rfloor $ can jump by as much as $4$...

Comment: @johnmangual elaborate, please?

Comment: He means that if $n$ has solution then one of $n+1,n+2,n+3$ or $n+4$ has solution. (I think)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First we will analyse the "simpler" function $\lfloor 2 x\rfloor +\lfloor 4 x\rfloor +\lfloor 8 x\rfloor$. To do this we will look at the jump points (the points where the function "jumps"). These occur at points of the form $\frac{k}{8}$ with $k$ an integer. We shall look at how much the function jumps depending on $k$. If $k$ is a multiple of $4$ then the function jumps by $2$. If $k$ is a multiple of $2$ but not of $4$ then it jumps by 2, and if $k$ is not a multiple of 2 it jumps by $1$. So if we add the first few jumps (starting at evaluating the function at $k=0$ we get:

$0$

$0+1=1$( the first jump, when $k=1$)

$1+2$ (the second jump, when $k=2$)

$3+1$ (the third jump, when $k=3$)

$4+3$ (the fourth jump, when $k=4$)

After this the magnitude of the jumps will continue to cycle. Therefore for this function $n$ has a solution if and only if $n$ leaves residue $0,1,3$ or $4$ when divided by $7$

Now let us look at the behaviour of the function $\lfloor \frac{x}{20} \rfloor$. Clearly this one jumps at points of the form $\frac{l}{20}$ when $k$ is an integer and jumps one at each point.

So now we can put both of these together by looking at jumps of the form $\frac{m}{40}$ Under the jumps for the first part of the function are the same as before. and the jumps for the second part only occur when $m$ is a multiple of $2$. Therefore we can make a new rule:  if $m$ We divide into two cases: if $m$ is a multiple of $2$ but not of 5: add 1. The next case is when $m$ is a multiple of $5$:if $m$ is not a multiple of $2$ add 1,if $m$ is a multiple of $2$ but not of $4$ add $3$, if $m$ is a multiple of $4$ add $4$. So calculating the first 40 values we get: $0, 
1, 
1, 
2, 
3, 
4, 
4, 
5, 
5, 
8, 
8, 
9, 
9, 
10, 
11, 
12, 
12, 
13, 
13, 
17, 
17, 
18, 
18, 
19, 
20, 
21, 
21, 
22, 
22, 
25, 
25, 
26, 
26, 
27, 
28, 
29, 
29, 
30, 
30, 
34$

So $n$ has a solutionf if and only if it leaves one of those residues when divided by $34$

Comment: Did you mean for your "simpler" function to be $\lfloor 2 x\rfloor +\lfloor 4 x\rfloor +\lfloor 8 x\rfloor$ instead?

Comment: Oh yes, my bad.

Comment: Your list is all wrong! To take two counterexamples at random, the function has value $3$ at $x=\frac5{40}$, and value $11$ at $x=\frac38$. Neither of these values is in your list.

Comment: Yes, it is wrong, but it is easily fixable

Comment: I've fixed it now

Answer (score 4):

Let's make a change of variables, that $x \mapsto \tfrac{x}{40}$, so our new function reads:

$$ f(x) = \lfloor \tfrac{x}{20} \rfloor +
\lfloor \tfrac{x}{10} \rfloor +
\lfloor \tfrac{x}{5}\rfloor +
\lfloor \tfrac{x}{2}  \rfloor $$

This is the sum of 4 step functions and we notice this function behaves kind of like a line:

$$
\begin{array}{ccc} 
f(x + 40) &=& 
\lfloor \tfrac{x + 40}{20} \rfloor +
\lfloor \tfrac{x + 40}{10} \rfloor +
\lfloor \tfrac{x + 40}{5}\rfloor +
\lfloor \tfrac{x + 40}{2}  \rfloor  \\\\
&=& 
(\lfloor \tfrac{x}{20} \rfloor + 2)+
(\lfloor \tfrac{x + 40}{10} \rfloor + 4)+
(\lfloor \tfrac{x + 40}{5}\rfloor  + 8)+
(\lfloor \tfrac{x + 40}{2}  \rfloor  + 20) \\\\
&=& \lfloor \tfrac{x}{20} \rfloor +
\lfloor \tfrac{x }{10} \rfloor +
\lfloor \tfrac{x }{5}\rfloor +
\lfloor \tfrac{x }{2}  \rfloor + 34 \\\\
&=& f(x) + 34
\end{array}
$$

[image]

Notice how the jumps are distributed like the lines on a ruler:

[image]

Here is a list of the values they obtain with some repetitions

```
0,  0,  1,  1,  2,  3,  4,  4,  5,  5,  8,  8,  9,  9, 10, 11, 12,
12, 13, 13, 17, 17, 18, 18, 19, 20, 21, 21, 22, 22, 25, 25, 26, 26,
27, 28, 29, 29, 30, 30
```

Comment: I really like the way you explain it. I just wasn't sure how to explain my ideas, but you really were able to take my answer and make it clear, +1.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x=I+f$, where $I \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $0 \leq f < 1$ (the fractional part). Then 
$\lfloor 2 x\rfloor = \lfloor 2I + 2f\rfloor =\begin{cases} 2I & \text{ if } 0 \leq f < \frac{1}{2} \\ 2I+1 & \text{ if } \frac{1}{2} \leq f < 1. \end{cases}$

Now do the same for other expressions and convert everything into equations with integer $I$ and solve.

## Second approach:

Let $f(x)=\lfloor 2 x\rfloor +\lfloor 4 x\rfloor +\lfloor 8 x\rfloor +\lfloor 20 x\rfloor$. Then for any $m \in \mathbb{Z}$, we have
$$f(x+m)=f(x)+34m.$$
Thus if we can express an integer $n$ as $f(x_0)$ for some $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$, then we can express all integers of the form $n+34m$ also in terms of $f$. So this reduces the problem of finding all the first $34$ integers that can be expressed as $f(x)$ when $x \in (0,1]$.

Comment: And how can he use this to answer the question?

Comment: for starters if $x=I$ (i.e. with $f=0$), then the equation reduces to $34I=n$. This means all integer multiples of $34$ that are less than $500$ will be solutions to this equation. Next he should investigate all $x$ of the form $x=I+f$, where $0 < f < \frac{1}{40}$ etc..